# How do you verify email and username with php and database with two different outputs for each?

Tags: php, sql, database

I am having a little problem. With my signup form, users have to enter username and email. I need to be able to check for both, while at the same time providing a separate output for each.

for example:

**User types in existing username: That username already exists.**

**User types in existing email: That email already exists.**

**User types in existing username and email: That username already exists. That email already exists.**

Get the point? Below is the code that I am using for it so far. When I submit, neither of the else statements run. If anyone has already found an article on site for this, please suggest it to me as I could not find one to help me so far.

```
if ($db_found) {
        $uSQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = $username";
        $uresult = mysql_query($uSQL);
        $unum_rows = mysql_num_rows($uresult);

        $eSQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = $email";
        $eresult = mysql_query($eSQL);
        $enum_rows = mysql_num_rows($eresult);

        if ($unum_rows > 0) {
            $errorMessage = "";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Username Already Exists";
        }
        if ($enum_rows > 0) {
            $errorMessage = "";
        }
        else {
            echo "Email Already Exists";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks good at first sight. Are you sure that $email and $username contain the correct input?

My first try would be doing an echo on the query and afterwards using this query in phpmyadmin to verify if it's correct.

Comment: True, the quotes are missing. ;)

Comment: Yes they are the correct inputs. The weird thing I just noticed is that if I leave and come back to the page, then the echo'd statements appear.

Comment: Strange. Is that issue still there? Or does it work now.

Comment: I actually figured it out. It was because I was echoing it in the wrong place...just a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. Your code seems to be correct. but I rather use count() from the database itself and add a single quotes to the arguments I pass to the SQL to avoid errors. also on count(*) use a single column like ID, username etc. is good SQL call only 1 column instead of * that means all Columns.

```
    if ($db_found) {

        $uSQL = "SELECT count(username) as total FROM login WHERE username = '$username';";
        $uresult = mysql_query($uSQL);
        $unum_rows =  mysql_fetch_array($uresult);

        if ($unum_rows['total'] > 0) {
            $errorMessage = "";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Username Already Exists";
        }


        $eSQL = "SELECT count(email) as total FROM login WHERE email = '$email';";
        $eresult = mysql_query($eSQL);
        $enum_rows = mysql_fetch_array($eresult);

        if ($enum_rows['total'] > 0) {
            $errorMessage = "";
        }
        else {
            echo "Email Already Exists";
        }
}
```